# trying to use the form object design pattern but getting this error: ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in PersonalTrainersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I'm very new to rails so dont really know what I am doing but I'm trying to use the form object design pattern. I've been trying to debug t for a while now and cant figure it out. Edit: i added this to the top of my controller: require'./lib/assets/personal_trainer_from'. Now I am getting this error:(**uninitialized constant PersonalTrainerForm::Virtus**).
This is the form that I am trying to use for the database

```
class PersonalTrainerForm
    include ActiveModel::Model
    include Virtus.model

    attribute :firstName, String
    attribute :secondName, String
    attribute :desription, String
    attribute :amountOfClients, Integer

    attr_reader :record

    def persist
        @personal_trainer = id ? PersonalTrainer.find(id) : PersonalTrainer.new
        if valid?
            @personal_trainer.save!
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end
end
```

This is my controller file

```
require './lib/assets/personal_trainer_from'
class PersonalTrainersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_personal_trainer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /personal_trainers
  # GET /personal_trainers.json
  def index
    @personal_trainers = PersonalTrainer.all

  end

  # GET /personal_trainers/1
  # GET /personal_trainers/1.json
  def show
    @personal_trainer_decorator = helpers.decorate(personal_trainer)

  end

  # GET /personal_trainers/new
  def new
    @personal_trainer = PersonalTrainer.new
  end

  # GET /personal_trainers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /personal_trainers
  # POST /personal_trainers.json
  def create
    @personal_trainer = PersonalTrainerForm.new(personal_trainer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @personal_trainer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @personal_trainer, notice: 'Personal trainer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @personal_trainer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @personal_trainer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /personal_trainers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /personal_trainers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @personal_trainer.update(personal_trainer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @personal_trainer, notice: 'Personal trainer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @personal_trainer }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @personal_trainer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /personal_trainers/1
  # DELETE /personal_trainers/1.json
  def destroy
    @personal_trainer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to personal_trainers_url, notice: 'Personal trainer was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_personal_trainer
      @personal_trainer = PersonalTrainer.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def personal_trainer_params
      params.require(:personal_trainer).permit(:firstName, :secondName, :desription, :amountOfClients)
    end
end
```

And finlally this is the full trace.

**
app/controllers/personal_trainers_controller.rb:30:in `create'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in`send_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:196:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in`process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in`run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in`process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in`block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in`instrument'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in`process_action'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in`process'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in`dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in`dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in`block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in`serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
rack-pjax (1.1.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in`call'
remotipart (1.4.4) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in`block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in`call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in`call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in`context'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in`call'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in`call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in`call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in`catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in`call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in`block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in`tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in`call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in`call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in`call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in`call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in`call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in`call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in`call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in`call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in`process_client'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in`block in spawn_thread' 
**
If there is anyone that can point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `personal_trainer_from` a typo for `personal_trainer_form`? That certainly can't be helping.

Comment: yeah it was a typo but i'm still gettig the same error